# DataGrid Row Highlight Being Removed on ItemSource Refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` of `People` that I can delete `People` from. After I delete a `Person` I call the following method;

```
private void SetSelectedPerson(int personDeleted, int personID)
{
    if (peopleDataGrid.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        peopleDataGrid.SelectedIndex--;
    }
    else
    {
        peopleDataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }  
}
```

This does select the previous `Row`, however it removes the highlighting from the `SelectedRow`. This is not what I want as although the `SelectedIndex` is correct, it does not look like the `Row` is selected to the user.

I do refresh the `DataGrid` `ItemSource` so that the deleted `Person` is removed from the current `Collection`. If I don't refresh the `ItemSource`, the highlighting is correct but of course the deleted `Person` is not removed from the `DataGrid`.

I refresh the `ItemSource` using;

```
  People = await ReturnPeople();
  PeopleICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(People);
  peopleDataGrid.ItemsSource = PeopleICollectionView;
  DataContext = this;
```

How can I keep the highlighting of the `Row` on an `ItemSource` update?

**EDIT:** For Sakura

This is how I Bind the `DataGrid` if I remove the hard code of `ItemSource`..

```
 People = await ReturnPeople();
 PeopleICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(People);
 DataContext = this;
```

And in the `XAML`;

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="peopleDataGrid" IsReadOnly="true" Margin="10,15,10,5" ColumnWidth="*" FontSize="14" 
                      HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                      SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleICollectionView}">
```

However when I delete a person it doesn't update in the `DataGrid`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I delete a Person I call the following method...

Firstly, if your `DataGrid` is single selected mode, when you delete selected item, the selected index will be set to -1. if it is multi selected mode, it will return index of one other selected item or -1 if don't have any. So you have to get the selected index of datagrid **before** you delete row. Then use this value after you delete.

Second, if your datagrid is binded correctly, you don't have to refresh the datacontext to make it update.
If you interested in fix this, post your binding code here.

Comment: I've actually fixed the original problem but I've updated my code as I'm interested in the binding issue

Comment: What is the type of `People` collection? `List`, `ObservableCollection<>`?

Comment: `public ICollectionView PeopleICollectionView { get; private set; }`

Comment: @CBreeze I ask about `People` which you use at `GetDefaultView(People)`, not about `PeopleICollectionView`. And when you delete row by press Delete key, does your DataGrid remove row?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, `var People = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();`. When I press `Delete` it is removed from the `MySQL` server then I get the `Data` again and rebind the `ItemsSource`

Comment: You should only send a delete command for deleted row. Don't clear `People` or `PeopleICollectionView`, don't rebind. It should auto be update.

Comment: Thanks for the Advice Sakura. I've tried using `peopleDataGrid.Items.Remove(selectedPerson);` but i get an error: `Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.` Any advice?

Comment: @CBreeze Use `People.Remove(peopleDataGrid.SelectedItem as PersonModel)` or  `People.Remove(selectedPerson as PersonModel)`